# Reading some integers then a line of text in C++

Tags: c++, string, input, newline, iostream

I'm reading input in a C++ program. First some integers, then a string. When I try reading the string with `getline(cin,stringname);`, it doesn't read the line that the user types: instead, I get an empty line, from when the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing the integers.

```
cin>>track.day; //Int
cin>>track.seriesday; //Int
getline(cin,track.comment); //String
```

How can I clear the `cin` (`cin.clear()` doesn't work) so that the string won't fill itself with the "enter" key?

It's a normal input receiving, nothing special at the top of the code,
I had a problem like this but I forgot the solution
I need to clear the `cin` someway so the string won't get filled with "enter" key.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please clarify.

Comment: Can you please paste the code where you read the integers? Also, what compiler are you using, and on which platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your cin of the ints is not reading the new line before the sentence. cin skips leading whitespace and stops reading a number when it encounters a non-digit, including whitespace.

So:

```
std::cin >> num1;
std::cin >> num2;
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // ignore the new line which follows num2
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
```

might work for you